# Can IBM Watson Assistant be integrated with Whatsapp or Workplace?

Tags: ibm-watson, whatsapp, watson-assistant, facebook-workplace

Has anyone worked on IBM Watson Assistant integration with Whatsapp or Workplace by Facebook? Which would be better to choose if feasible? Any suggestion/link/detail would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As long as the 3rd party app allows to integrate, it can be integrated

Comment: Yup, i've integrated Watson with Whatsapp in a node app and twilio

Answer (score 0):

Watson Assistant can be integrated directly with Facebook. It can be integrated to WhatsApp also but this one needs Twilio WhatsApp API service. There are other third-party integrating services like this one for WhatsApp. IBM suggests Twilio. It has it's [advantages](https://sleekflow.io/blog/whatsapp-business-chatapi-and-twilio).

Here you can find the documentation related to Watson Assistant and it's [tutorials](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson-assistant?topic=watson-assistant-welcome-new-assistant) by IBM, here Twilio [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00wIbg0zjnQ&ab_channel=IBMDeveloper) to integrate the assistant with WA.